# What is getStringExtra format

Tags: java, android

```
//intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "abc");
intent.getStringExtra(Home.EXTRA_MESSAGE) == "abc" // false
intent.getStringExtra(Home.EXTRA_MESSAGE) == getString(R.string.abc) //false (with R.string.abc=="abc")

String abc = "abc";
intent.getStringExtra(Home.EXTRA_MESSAGE) == abc //false
```

Why everything is false?
If I print the values with a toast they're apparently identical.

Thanks.

Comment: don't use == to compare strings, use String.equals().

Comment: Why are you used `getStringExtra()` if you have `putExtra()` with String, rather than you can use  `getString()` and directly company with `.equals("your string");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare the values of two java `String`'s with .equals:

```
str1.equals(str)
```

In this context, `==` compares whether those two `String`'s are the same objects, and they are not, thus evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Well first and foremost, you can't compare strings with == ...

You need to be comparing two strings with string1.equals(string2)

Then you should get a "true" result.

hope this helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

== compare whether both the string objects are same.(I.e address of object)

equals () method compare whether both the string objects have same value or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to understand this code and the results below to see the difference between == and equals(). Then you'll see why equals() is usually what you want for comparing strings.**

```
String string1 = "android";
String string2 = "android";
String string3 = new String("android");

if(string1 == string2){
   System.out.print("String1 == String2");
}else{
   System.out.print("String1 != String2");
}

if(string1.equals(string2)){
   System.out.print("String1 equals String2");
}else{
   System.out.print("String1 not equals String2");
}

if(string1 == string3){
   System.out.print("String1 == String3");
}else{
   System.out.print("String1 != String3");
}

if(string1.equals(string3)){
   System.out.print("String1 equals String3");
}else{
   System.out.print("String1 not equals String3");
}

if(string2 == string3){
   System.out.print("String2 == String3");
}else{
   System.out.print("String2 != String3");
}

if(string2.equals(string3)){
   System.out.print("String2 equals String3");
}else{
   System.out.print("String2 not equals String3");
}
```

**Result :**

```
>> String1 == String2
>> String1 equals String2
>> String1 != String3
>> String1 equals String3
>> String2 != String3
>> String2 equals String3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out `equals()` Instead `==` like:

```
//intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "abc");
intent.getStringExtra(Home.EXTRA_MESSAGE).equals("abc");
intent.getStringExtra(Home.EXTRA_MESSAGE).equals(getString(R.string.abc));

String abc = "abc";
intent.getStringExtra(Home.EXTRA_MESSAGE).equals(abc);
```

> Note: If you have set values using `putExtra(key, String)` then you can simply get values using `intent.getString(key).`